# gdb: how to disassemble non-struction piece of code?

Tags: gdb, nasm, disassembly

Having this in nasm:

```
section .data
cod: db '0123456789ABCDEF'

section .text
global _start
_start:
    nop
    mov rax, 0x1122334455667788
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rdx, 1
    mov rcx, 64

.loop:
    push rax
    sub rcx, 4
    sar rax, cl
    and rax, 0xf
    lea rsi, [cod + rax]
    mov rax, 1
    push rcx
    syscall
    pop rcx
    pop rax
    test rcx, rcx
    jnz .loop
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

The in gdb:
`disas _start.loop`
gives:
`Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure.`

How can I disas the loop in gdb?

PS: I would also like to know, what is meant in gdb as structs. I suppose, it has nothing to do with `c` structs, but rather function frames? So gdb can see where the function start and ens? So in my case, it is a loop, not a function so it does not have any frames. Is that mean by the error?

EDIT:
I have tried steping in gdb:

```
(gdb) break *_start+1
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000401001 in _start ()
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function _start,
which has no line number information.
```

And then output
`1122334455667788[Inferior 1 (process 6257) exited normally]`

BUT, I have not seen any instruction from `<_start.loop>` loop, It just exit from _start. 
I do not know whether it is because of `.loop` nasm directive or it does not have "struct behavior", but how can I see the piece of code `.loop` in gdb before exiting from `_start`?

Comment: .loop is not a directive. It's just a label for goto.

Comment: Ok, but anyway, why does gdb not want to show code after it (and rather exit first)?

Comment: Why GDB does this, unknown, but to solve your problem I've changed `.loop` to `Loop` and it works. I thought it might have something to do with `loop` being an instruction, but `.lmp` did the same thing.

Comment: @Herdsman I do not know. I have never run into this problem.

Comment: Add quotes around it so that gdb doesn't think it's a C struct element. `disas '_start.loop'`